# Darktable XMP sidecar filters repository

Tags: filters, darktable, sharing, xmp, sidecar

Maybe I'm asking a stupid question for real photographers, but I'm searching an online repository with [XMP sidecar](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/sidecar_files.html) files for Darktable. Everyone knows the many instagram effects like laté and sepia and so on. Is there no place where photographers share some of this effects and editing steps in XMP sidecar files? So I can use them and learn quickly from these predefined files.

Answer (score 4):

There's https://dtstyle.net

It's a repository of *.dtstyle files, not XMP files... those are generally used for file-specific information. Styles can be managed in [the "Styles" panel](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/styles.html) on the right-hand side in lighttable mode.

Comment: Wow, I was really searching for something like that. I will experiment with it :)

Answer (score -1):

There is a LUT module in darktable now, so you can apply a LUT to your image, which is useful for all those instagram-type filters.

Comment: This seems to me to be only tangentially related to the question, which wasn't about what Darktable supports but about where to find settings which other photographers have found useful.